# C++ Function Call vs. New Blocks for Push/Popping on the Stack

Tags: c++, stack, block, function-calls

I was reading about variable scope in C++ and encountered an interesting block structure:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int local;

    { // New level of scope
        int more_local;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I understand that variables are popped out of the stack at the end of each block denoted by the closing curly brace `}`.

I've also read that function calls also push their variables on the stack and terminate at the end of the call denoted by closing curly brace `}`:

```
void foo() {
    int more_local;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int local;
    foo();

    return 0;
}
```

How is the stack handled differently in both situations and what are the advantages and disadvantage of both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could say that your first example could be seen as an inlined function. :P
But generally, function calls and opening a new `scope` have nothing to do with each other.
When you call a function, the return address and all arguments are pushed on the stacked and popped from it after the function returns.
When opening a new `scope`, you simple call the destructor of all objects within that scope at the end of it; it is by no means guaranteed that the actual space occupied by those variables is popped from the stack right away. It could, but the space could also simply be reused by other variables in the function, depending on the compilers / optimizers whims.

Comment: I think you mean constructor, not destructor, as the destructor is called at the end of a scope.

Comment: I just read about _inline functions_: "When the compiler inline-expands a function call, the function's code gets inserted into the caller's code stream" If I _inlined_ the second example's function, would it be any different from the first example?

Comment: Careful, **the compiler** inline-expands a function call, not you.  Even if you use the _inline_ keyword, it's just a hint to the compiler.  The function may or may not be inlined during compilation, depending on what the compiler ultimately decides.

Answer (score 4):

With the function call, you are pushing the return address onto the stack and creating a new *stack frame*.  If you just enclose parts of code in curly braces, you are defining a new scope, as you said.  They are just like any block of code following a control statement such as if, for, while, etc.

You can't really talk about advantages and disadvantages here, because these are two completely different things.  There aren't very many situations where you will benefit from enclosing blocks of code in curly braces, and it can make code harder to read.

Comment: If I compile both examples above, I would assume that the example with  _new scope_ will be micro-optimized in contrast to the function call because of the extra overhead associated with creating a new _stack frame_. Isn't this an advantage? I may have some errors in my logic but it seems like there is a performance difference (no matter how small).

Comment: Sure, if your objective is only to create a new scope, then use the curly braces. But why do you want to do that? If it's to reuse variable names I would caution against it. If it's to try to optimize your memory usage I wouldn't try to micro-manage it like that; the compiler should be able to optimize it well enough.

Comment: @Gio: Depending on the optimization level (`/O1` should already be enough), that function call will most likely be inlined, depending on its actual length and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

`int more_local;` will be placed on the stack in both cases. But second scenario will have an overhead of function call.

I would suggest you to think about rather this:

```
void foo()
{
    int local;

    { // New level of scope
        int more_local_1;
    }
    { // New level of scope
        int more_local_2;
    }
}
```

Here `more_local_1` and `more_local_2` may share the same memory location. Once it used for 
`more_local_1` and in second scope for `more_local_2` variable.

Answer (score 1):

- local scopes can still access the other local variables, while functions have to be explicitly passed any of the caller's variables they need to use

  - passing variables is a pain, but sometimes it makes code more understandable to clearly indicate the smaller set of variables actually needed for the scoped operations (as well as encouraging operations to be grouped into discrete functional units, given an appropriate function name and context-relevant parameter names, and they're then ready for reuse)
- out-of-line function calls have a few other stack space & performance overheads: return addresses, saved registers, call and return instructions
- compared to function scope, local scopes are particularly good for minimising the scope of variables that hold important resources such as larger amounts of memory, threads, file descriptors and/or locks: the higher-level and longer-running the function the more useful it might be to clean it up promptly

  - reduced variable lifetime also reduces the number of concurrent variables the programmer has to mentally "track" to comprehend and maintain the code: the less the better
- sometimes it doesn't make much sense to have to choose arbitrary different identifiers when you're doing a set of similar operations, so some local scopes allow the identifier to be "recycled" conveniently
- local scopes are a bit clumsy and take "screen space" in source code, as well as increasing indentation level, so it's a good idea to use them when there's a specific justification rather than on a "whenever you can" basis

Answer (score 0):

If you observe the assembly code for both the programs it seems that there is no difference because compiler seems to generate assembly code to push a new stack frame at current stack pointer when it encounters a opening curly brace or a function call and pop the frame out once it encounters closing curly brace or return statement.The advantage in second case is that you can return a value with return statement to caller function. But not in first case.